# Adding columns in sequelize without resetting database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm working with a Sequelize Postgres database, and I'm aware I can add a column by adding it to my schema, then running `sequelize.sync({ force: true })`.

That basically throws out my whole database and creates a new one.

Obviously that's not going to be a viable solution forever, but I can't work out how to add a new column any other way. Currently if I add a column to my schema and run: `sequelize.sync({ force: false })`, it doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't add any new columns, so I just get `column "foo" does not exist` until I throw out my entire database and start again.

*Surely* there's a way of adding a column without resetting everything? Is there an option I'm missing? I can't spot it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sequelize.  Q: Is this a "real" PostgreSQL RDBMS, and you're just using Sequalize to access it from NodeJS?  Q: Can't you just log in to the database directly and give the standard SQL command [ALTER DATABASE ADD COLUMN...](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-add-column/)?

Comment: You have to use migrations. Refer to this. https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-sequelize-to-manipulate-databases-2f2f22c0e9ad

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize includes the ability to use migrations for databases. In reality this is something you should be building with your changes as you go, though I can understand not doing so if this is the first instance and creation. However when your site goes into production you will need to use migrations to smoothly update the database.
Take a look at the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html).

From the CLI you can create a new migration file and edit it to include your new fields. You still need them in your model file as you've already done.